# Command not working inside execSync in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have one shell command which is working fine from terminal but when I try to run from nodejs it is giving me the error

Orignal Command

```
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{n+=gsub(/\n/, "&")} END{print n}' <(sed '$s/$//' file.txt)
```

Node Js Code

```
  execSync("awk -v RS='\"[^\"]*\"' '{n+=gsub(/\\n/, \"&\")} END{print n}' <(sed '$s/$//' "+ filePath+')')
```

The exesync is giving the same output but it is showing me the error Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<()` is a bash-specific [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) syntax. `execSync` defaults to using `/bin/sh`, usually a narrowly POSIX-compliant shell, which means it doesn't support the syntax. Explicitly use bash instead:

```js
execSync("command goes here", {
    shell: "/bin/bash"
});
```

Comment: execSync("awk -v RS='\"[^\"]*\"' '{n+=gsub(/\\n/, \"&\")} END{print n}' <(sed '$s/$//' "+ filePath+')', {
            shell: "bin/bash"
        });
It is giving me error Error: spawnSync bin/bash ENOENT

Comment: @user13000875 Oops, I forgot a leading slash. I've edited my answer, please try it again.

Comment: @user13000875 Did you find a solution?